# Crashlytics and Proguard with -dontobfuscate

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics

I have an application in which I want to use proguard to "strip out" unused functions, etc. but I have code obfuscation disabled to play nicely with Dagger.  However, now crashlytics seems to fail, saying that it can't find the mapping.txt file.

This makes sense, because the mapping.txt file shouldn't exist, as there's nothing to map, because we aren't doing a mapping....

Is there some configuration I can do to force a mapping file generation in proguard, or to disable the deobfuscation side of crashlytics?

Answer (score 2):

A mapping file is just a text file with one line for each class/field/method that is obfuscated, so you could create an empty mapping.txt file in your build process. That should appease Crashlytics.

Note that you can obfuscate Dagger code too. You just need to preserve the class dagger.Lazy, the classes that Dagger generates (with '$$'), and the corresponding base classes (with -keep). You'll probably see ClassNotFoundExceptions or similar exceptions for any classes that are still missing.